# creating periodic tasks set in verilog

Tags: verilog, periodic-task

I want to create a set of periodic tasks set with different period and execution time, in verilog module, that task will create so will operate some sorts of operation and shall be executed after certain periods...

So, In higher level language like in c

```
func()
{
for(;;)
}
and sleep()
```

I think, i would use that func() as operation and after sleep()..this func() shall be called again...
is this a right way to do so in verilog?? and Can I also measure the execution time as well as period in testbench...after  simulation..
any suggestion would be highly helpful

regards

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
always begin
  // do stuff
  # amount of nanoseconds to wait until next execution
end
```

For example: this periodic task increments variable `counter` every 1.5 microsecond.

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
integer counter = 0;
always begin
  counter = counter + 1;
  #1500;
end
```

Use `` `timescale `` with different units if you don't need nanosecond precision. For example, the previous block could be written as this:

```
`timescale 1us/1ns
integer counter = 0;
always begin
  counter = counter + 1;
  #1.5;
end
```

**EDIT**

It is important to make clear that simulated delays, denoted by `#{insert_delay}`, cannot be synthesized. They should only be used in a test bench to model delays coming from a driver. So of your `func()` and `sleep()` are not in a testbench, they will need to be modeled as some sort of counter, that resets then counts `x` number of clock pulses.

Comment: hi, so the delays would not get reflected when it get synthesized that is on fpga when it will run...would u elaborate what the changes that need to be made in verilog module